# Get the exact number the user Entered

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular, and i have this application where users enter a specific budget expample : 18278,85 in a form but after submit it's displayed like this :  18278,8 and that not what i want.
How can i display the exact number like this users enter 18278,85 => display 18278,85 and if the users enter 2 it will stay 2 no 2,00.

here what i have in my code :

```
 <td>{{deviline.montant_ht| number}} {{deviline.devise}}</td>
```

Thank you for yout help

Comment: fyi, I removed the `php` tag since it seemed unrelated

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you can just use Angular's built-in `CurrencyPipe`.

For example:

```
public a = "123456.11";
public b = "123456.00";

{{ a | currency : 'USD' : 'symbol' : '2.0-2' }}
{{ b | currency : 'USD' : 'symbol' : '2.0-2' }}
```

Results in

```
123,456.11
123,456
```

Comment: Thanks for you replay but if i do like this the number change and i don't want that the user entered 18278,85 and it become 18 279 or i want it to stay 18278,85.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Number pipe like this:

```
{{deviline.montant_ht| number: '1.0-4'}}
```

The first number(1) is the number of the minimal number digits

The second number (0) is the minimal number of decimal digits

The last number(2) is the max number of digits you want.

In this example, 2 will be shown as 2 and 18278,85 will display as 18278,85.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that you "change" the properties of the object `deviline` when you submit (as is an object remember that any change in the property, e.g. "devise" in your function submit or in any another function that you call in submit and pass as argument, change the own object). Remember, the object are pass always by reference. You can use spread operator if you what a copy of a simple object

```
submit(form:FormGroup)
{
   this.myService.update({...form.value})
}
```